# A few questions about how to not use resources in my android project

Tags: android

My Android project is intended to be distributional as a reusable library, as a jar.  My understanding is that I can not use any resources (no references to the static R class).  I have a couple of questions about how to do this.

What is a good way to handle drawables?  If I include an image on my sourcepath at /images/image.png then I can load it with the below code.  Is this a good strategy?

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.png");
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

How should I handle internationalization?  I guess I could include all my strings into a Java class and than return one based on the device's language.  But, would this be a memory burden on my app?  Also, what is the proper way to determine the device's language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason for distributing it as a jar? I would advice you to distribute it as a Library Project instead. Android Library Projects, described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html), will let you use the static R class the same way you use it in a normal project, and you will have the ability to handle internationalization as well.

A very good reason for using a library project is the fact that resources placed in the res/ folder are heavily compressed compile-time to decrease the final size of you binary. This is true both for images and xml files.

Comment: Because I don't want it to be open source and this would require me to distribute source code?

Comment: If you absolutely cannot distribute your code, then I guess this is not the solution you are looking for. As far as I know, there is no way of distributing a library project compiled to a jar. Mark Murphy discusses some solutiont here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269816/creating-closed-source-android-libraries), but in the end it seems there is no really good way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks, Mark Murphy's discussion is what I was looking for